# Official C++ language and base class library documentations?

Tags: c++, documentation, standards

I'm newbie on C++. And I have multiple years of C# background.
In C#, official language standard and basic class library documentations can be found on MSDN.
What's the equivalent for C++?

And what's the most basic library of C++? There are many libraries. Boost, STL, ATL, and etc... What's the most basic and I should start from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The equivalent is [The ISO C++ Standard](http://webstore.ansi.org/RecordDetail.aspx?sku=INCITS/ISO/IEC%2014882-2003).  The last revision was published in 2003 (the link is to where you can purchase the PDF of that document).  The next revision, what is called C++0x, is slated to be finished sometime around the end of this year (the latest draft can be downloaded freely from the C++ committee website; a very large PDF can be found [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3225.pdf)).

The most basic library for C++ is just called the C++ Standard Library.  It should be supported by every C++ compiler.

Comment: MSDN also documents the STL http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscc687y.aspx

Comment: @Mark:  MSDN documents _The Microsoft Visual C++ implementation of the STL_.  It's quite likely that there are some things in the MSDN documentation that are Microsoft-specific (often these things are in blocks demarcated by "BEGIN/END MICROSOFT SPECIFIC," but occasionally they are not).

Comment: Thanks for especially 'C++ Standard Library'. Everyone around me have  talked `no such thing for C++` :)

Comment: @Eonil:  Well, it isn't at all the same as the BCL.  The C++ Standard Library is very minimalistic and is designed to provide functionality that most any platform can support and that most programs will use.  It just provides the building blocks on top of which other libraries can provide other functionality.

Comment: It's enough for me. Small is beautiful.

Answer (score 0):

For a good treatment of the standard library you might want to read Stroustrup's [The C++ Programming Language](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/3rd.html). Also, note that the STL is actually part of the standard library, or well, partly really.